# Registering classes in 2.80

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to start developing in the new beta build environment. For that, I want to register classes the new way:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons

However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Also, when trying
"help(bpy.utils.register_class_factory())" in the inteactive python console, I get:

> AttributeError: module 'bpy.utils' has no attribute 'register_class_factory'

Some simplified code I am "working" on right now:

```
import bpy

class MakeProxy(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_OT_object_make_proxy"
    bl_label = "mProxy"

    "more code"

classes = (
    MakeProxy
    )

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_object_make_proxy(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.make_proxy"
    bl_label = "Make Proxy"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        pass # More code here
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = (
            OBJECT_OT_object_make_proxy,

          )

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This works.

I do not understand what they mean to say about the new naming conventions [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons). Browsing the web it seems I am not the only one.

It says:

> This constraint applies to the bl_idname of each class (or the class
>   name which uses it if no bl_idname is defined in the class).
>
> These are: UPPER_CASE_{SEPARATOR}_mixed_case, in the case of a menu
>   the regular expression is:
>
> > [A-Z][A-Z0-9_]**MT*[A-Za-z0-9_]+
>
> The separator for each class is listed below:
>
> > Header -> *HT* 
> >     Menu -> *MT* 
> >     Operator -> *OT* 
> >     Panel -> *PT* 
> >     UIList -> *UL*
>
> Valid Examples:
>
> > OBJECT_OT_fancy_tool 
> >     SOME_HEADER_HT_my_header 
> >     PANEL123_PT_myPanel (lower case is preferred but mixed case is supported).
>
> At the time of writing this, names that don't conform to this
>   convention will produce a warning on startup. Eventually we will make
>   this into an error, eg:
>
> Warning: 'Oscurart Files Tools' doesn't contain '*PT*' with prefix &
>   suffix Warning: 'Oscurart Overrides' doesn't contain '*PT*' with
>   prefix & suffix Warning: 'Oscurart Animation Tools' doesn't contain
>   '*PT*' with prefix & suffix

So this might mean that the `bl_idname` should actually be 
something like `"object.MY_ADDON_OT_some_object_operator"`
It still requires a '.' to be there so `object.OBJECT_OT_something_something` does not seem to make much sense to me. Let's make this a [new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124095/what-do-new-bpy-class-naming-conventions-in-blender-2-80-actually-mean) as well, maybe someone else knows.

Comment: Okay, although I dont yet onehundred percent understand why it works, it does not throw any errors on compilation anymore. I am hoping for more clarification in the other question.

However: I am not able to call my function from the "spacebar - search - window", as I was able to in 2.79. Any thoughts on that, maybe? Please? :)

Comment: The way I understand it, what was wrong in your script were two things: bl_idname requires a '.' character to be in it, and the arguement for `bpy.utils.register_classes_factory()` needs to be iterable, so you need a comma after the value you assign to it or to make it a list first you could do `classes = list()` followed by `classes.append(some_single_class)` if you wanted a list with a single element. If you search for what you have in bl_label while poll() returns true, you should find the operator with the search.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just copied your exact script, rather than just trying to fix mine and yours works. So I am doing something wrong, obviously. Thank you so much for your time!