# bl_idname convention

Tags: python

Blender Wiki notes the following about bl_idname convention.

[BlenderWikiAddon](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons)

"For headers, menus and panels, the bl_idname is expected to match the class name (automatic if none is specified).

Valid Examples:

```
class OBJECT_OT_fancy_tool (and bl_idname = "object.fancy_tool")
class MyFancyTool (and bl_idname = "MYADDON_MT_MyFancyTool")
```

"
In other Blender Python documentation I noted also:
[PythonDocumentationPanel](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html)

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello_world"

and

class PanelOne(View3DPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_test_1"

I struggle to grasp how all these are valid as the demand is "expected to match the class name".

Can you shade light on the convention or refer me to the right source, so I know how and when to use Upper, Lower, Mix case?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124095/what-do-new-bpy-class-naming-conventions-in-blender-2-80-actually-mean

Comment: Also this is the same but more direct: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/class-naming-conventions-in-blender-2-8-python-api/

Comment: the document states UPPER_CASE_{SEPARATOR}_mixed_case. Below in the valid exemples it shows:  bl_idname = 'myaddon.my_operator' and bl_idname = 'MYADDON_MT_my_menu'... But how the lower case example is also valid?

Comment: @Psyonic the document states UPPER_CASE_{SEPARATOR}_mixed_case. Below in the valid exemples it shows: bl_idname = 'myaddon.my_operator' and bl_idname = 'MYADDON_MT_my_menu'... But how the lower case example is also valid?

Comment: I don't know **why**, you'll have to ask the developers, maybe @batFINGER knows, but the operators use 'lowercase.my_operator' and the rest use 'UPPERCASE_XX_my_name' (note the dot verses underscore) From what I've used, anything will work, Blender will complain but not break, it's just for convention so we're all talking the same language for projects with multiple people working on them.

Comment: Having a hard time to understand your question. `MyFancyTool` as well as `MyFancyPanel` is valid because of PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names However, the recommended way is the one you've already found in the release notes, `CUSTOM_PT_myPanel` or `CUSTOM_OT_myOperator` for the class name. When it comes to operators, the most important thing to note is that they can be called using `bpy.ops.*` ... bpy.ops + namespace + your name to classify whether it is an operator for meshes, lights, cameras or whatnot, `bpy.ops.namespace.my_fancy_tool()`. Does this help?

Comment: Best practice (and blender convention) prefers class names to be camel case `HelloWorldPanel`  When a class is registered, it is known to blender via its `bl_idname` (in template example case) `bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_hello`    Can leave out the `bl_idname` and it registers as `bpy.types.HelloWorldPanel` (with the warning) which is undesirable, particularly if for instance it was named "Panel"  (wont reg, but imagine the hassles if it did)  Hence for panels and menus my suggestion is stick to using a `bl_idname` with the convention, rather than the alternate of class naming via convention.